# Is it ok to plug in battery backward to do compression test?

Tags: electrical, wiring, small-engine, compression-testing, compression-release

On engines with compression release valves, the recommended method for testing compression is turning the engine in reverse direction.  I'm working on a lawn tractor (with a Kholer K241AQS), so there aren't a lot of fancy electric systems.  What complications would arise from simply plugging my battery in backwards?  (Being DC, my starter should run in reverse direction.)

Comment: Using a chassis for a ground is one thing, but using it for the hot side is asking for a fire.

Comment: @cory, why?  I mean, what component would cause a fire if the electron flow is reversed?

Comment: When you do whatever, ensure you disconnect the battery before you start. This could physically disasterous if something should happen and the starter engages going forward.

Comment: You never turn it backwards for a compression test, where did you get this information?

Comment: @Moab, This is a small engine with an automatic compression release, so you don't get good compression readings when cranking "normally" – I have no personal experience, but it sounds like some people claim that you can defeat the compression release and get a good reading by cranking the engine backwards.

Comment: @dlu, Right on.  It's not an issue on bigger motors, but with some small engines, the compression release valve gives a deceptively low rating.  (http://www.repairfaq.org/samnew/lmfaq/lmcomptst.htm, http://www.briggsandstratton.com/eu/en/support/faqs/compression-system, http://www.abbysguide.com/ope/discussions/25489-A-1.html)

Comment: @anonymous2 When things are connected to the hot side of a battery, they are fused as close to the battery as possible, so that in the event of a short to ground, the power is cut. When the entire chassis is the hot side, there's no fuse by the battery, and given the chassis is hot, it's very easy to short to ground.

Comment: @cory It's not easier to short to ground, because the only things which are "grounded" are the things which were formerly "hot" - and which are presumably insulated. The fuse is also still close to the battery, and will still work in exactly the same way; the only real reason to not fuse the negative side of the battery is that the usual wiring layout makes it difficult to isolate circuits on that side. The confusion likely comes from using "hot" and "ground", which are terms from the AC domain where the "hot" is a voltage relative to the earth/ground - which is everywhere and hard to avoid.:)

Comment: @cory There is not ground in a car.   There is positive and a negative.  Reversing is still not a good idea.

Comment: @Paparazzi No ground exists in a car, just a plus sign and a minus sign on the battery. Got it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This engine is equipped with a voltage regulator. Depending on the exact construction of the regulator a reverse current would be disastrous, especially the high current from a starter battery [image]

Comment: Thanks, @Myself.  This was kind of what I was looking for.  So flipping the battery around would blow up my voltage regulator?

Comment: And since there would be lots of heat generated, you could melt or fry other things as well. Connecting your battery backwards, even on something this straight forward is asking for trouble and fried parts.

Comment: Most possible, yes. There are some kind of voltage regulators around who are immune against it, but we cannot be sure about the internal construction of the regulator. Besides, nobody will give you a guarantee that there are no other traps hidden.

Comment: All automotive-grade electronics *must* be designed to protect against reverse polarity on the battery - it's one of the standard parts of making something automotive-grade electronics.  It's possible that your lawn tractor isn't using a standard off-the-shelf alternator, but it seems unlikely they'd design it themselves at a much-increased cost, when they can just buy a standard item.

Comment: On designing for reverse polarity: http://electronicdesign.com/power/reverse-polarity-protection-automotive-design

Comment: ty, I learned something new today

Answer (score 9):

Why not just put a wrench on the crankshaft? Ignoring the electrical repercussions, I fear damage to the starter, too. Besides, if the starter on this tractor uses a sprag clutch (and probably most other designs), it wont engage backwards, anyway.

Comment: Good point, @justinm410.  I believe my motor does have a sprag clutch.

Comment: And BTW, I would opt for a rope around the flywheel, as I'll be better able to get the motor going fast enough for a good compression reading.  Just means taking the motor covering off.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like the starter drive is the typical spring loaded drive gear that engages when the starter motor turns in the "forward" direction, then disengages if the engine starts running and overdrives the starter gear forcing it to disengage. So if you run the starter motor backwards, the starter gear won't engage at all, and the starter will just spin. And without being loaded down by the force needed to spin the engine, it may spin too fast and become damaged.

So, even if your electrical system could handle it (and it almost certainly can't), the starter won't run the engine backwards.

[image]

*(image from [partstree.com](https://www.partstree.com/parts/cub-cadet/mowers-lawn-garden-tractor/1000-2050550u-2050540u-cub-cadet-garden-tractor/engine-k241aqs-10-horsepower/))*

Answer (score 5):

Even if there are no polarity-sensitive electronics to damage and the starter motor was able to engage, it is unlikely that the motor would rotate backwards anyway.

Most car starter motors (in fact all that I have worked with) do not use permanent magnets, instead opting for coils for the stator. I suspect the same may be true for your lawn tractor.

Therefore both the stator and rotors are using coils from the same feed and reversing the polarity of the feed reverses the direction of the magnetic fields on both the stator coils and rotor coil - the result being that the motor will rotate in the same direction as before anyway.

On a permanent magnet motor, you effectively just reverse one magnetic field (the rotor) when reversing polarity, and that it why they will rotate in the opposite direction.

Comment: Good point, though in my case it is indeed permanent magnets - it's an old tractor without many of the modern features.